# Generalizing compile-time and run-time evaluation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compile-time

In some occasions, I may need to use the same behavior/code, with values that sometimes are known at run-time and at compile-time. This leads to code repetition:

```
template<int TValue> struct CompileTime
{
    int duplicate() { return TValue * 2; }
};

struct RunTime
{
    int value;
    RunTime(int mValue) : value{mValue} { }
    int duplicate() { return value * 2; }
};

int main()
{
    // I need to duplicate a compile-time known value first...
    CompileTime<2>{}.duplicate();

    // And now I need to duplicate a run-time value...
    int value; std::cin >> value;
    RunTime{value}.duplicate();
}
```

Obviously the example is really stupid, but is there any way I can avoid repeating the behavior of `duplicate()`? *(The value needs to be stored, however.)*

Ideally, I'd like to write:

```
int main() 
{
    // 2 is known at compile-time, calls a "templatized" version of `duplicate`
    UnknownTime<2>{}.duplicate(); 

    // `value` is known at run time, calls a "run-time" version of `duplicate`
    int value; std::cin >> value;
    UnknownTime<value>{}.duplicate();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot make templates instantiate at runtime, you can however ditch templates altogether and use c++11 `constexpr`, which was added to the language exactly for this purpose:

```
struct AnyTime
{
    int value;
    constexpr AnyTime(int mValue) : value{mValue} { }
    constexpr int duplicate() const { return value * 2; }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int compileTime = AnyTime{2}.duplicate();

    int value; std::cin >> value;
    int runTime = AnyTime{value}.duplicate();
}
```

Comment: You should explicitly mark `duplicate()` as `const`, not just `constexpr`, to be compatible with C++14. Otherwise, `constexpr AnyTime at{2}; at.duplicate();` won't compile.

Comment: [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/501641f29c354f0a). This answer should ideally explain _why_ and _how_ `constexpr` solves the problem, though.

Comment: Funny, though, I thought `AnyTime::value` would have to be `constexpr` for this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: a "static" value has to be `constexpr`, but a regular data member does not (and can thus be modified).

Answer (score 0):

In cases like `duplicate` you could move to using functions, rather than classes or structures:

```
template<int TValue>
int duplicate()
{
    return TValue * 2;
}

int duplicate(int value)
{
    return value * 2;
}
```

Now you can say:

```
int main() 
{
    // 2 is known at compile-time, calls a "templatized" version of `duplicate`
    int value1 = duplicate<2>(); 

    // `value` is known at run time, calls a "run-time" version of `duplicate`
    int value; std::cin >> value;
    int value2 = duplicate(value);
}
```